# How to implement compatible up navigation?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

**EDIT :** I decided to make this app compatible with API 11 and above only. The up button still doesn't work properly, though.

I need to use the up button functionality in my Android app, and I want to make it compatible with all versions starting from API level 11 (version 3.0). Now, I have no problem navigating up from an activity in version 3.2. But now I'm testing on Android 4.2 and it doesn't work; it just exits the app immediately. Could someone tell me what I'm missing?

I defined the parent activity in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
...
    <activity
        android:name="net.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name="net.example.myapp.DetailActivity"
        android:parentActivityName="net.example.myapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="net.example.myapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
...
```

And in my child activity:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

...
```

Comment: Why API7? Is that still a serious consideration?

Comment: @323go Because I was originally asked to make our Android apps as compatible as possible (and I had to make a previous app prototype work on Android 2.3); I'm not sure whether it's worth it, though.

Comment: Understood, you might want to reconsider. Based on the [Android Dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), API7 isn't even checking into the play store anymore, and API8 has less than one in two-hundred users. We generally go API10+ for phone-apps, and API15+ for tablet apps.

Answer (score 0):

The [Providing Up Navigation training](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) goes through all of the steps required for implementing backward compatible Up functionality.

As the Action Bar was only added in API 11 (and has changed multiple times since then, most recently for API 21's Material Design), you can use [AppCompat](https://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html#v7-appcompat) to provide a consistent Action Bar which is compatible through API 7 and gives you the same [Material Design Action Bar](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html) as is found on the newest devices.

Comment: I already checked the Android docs on that. It still doesnt work. The Action bar itself is not an issue, by the way; just the up navigation.

Comment: What does `NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)` return? Does your `onCreate()` for `MainActivity` get called?

Comment: The `onCreate()` for my MainActivity is getting called. That's where the menu is being displayed, and I can see it.
Now, I called `NavUtils.getParentActivityIntent(this)` and saved the result to an Object, then I logged it like this: `Log.w("[onOptionsItemSelected]", obj.toString());` and it returns `Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=net.example.myapp/.MainActivity }` So does that mean the app thinks it's in the MainActivity when it's in Detail Activity when going up?